# Sorting jpa nested entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have following entity in Spring Java JPA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "todo")
public class TodoEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private Long userId;

    private String text;

    private String description;

    private Boolean expanded;

    private Boolean completed;

    private Integer sortOrder;

    private Date expiredDate;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date creationDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updateDate;

    private Integer priority;

    private Long parentId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Set<TodoEntity> children;

    .....getter and setter

}
```

Now my issue is the sorting of the children.
I would like to sort them sometimes by date, sometimes by sortOrder (so basically with different parameters).

How to do that within JPA?

---

Info:

- Using Spring JPA data repositories

The repository:

```
@Repository
public interface TodoRepository extends JpaRepository<TodoEntity, Long> {

    Page<TodoEntity> findByUserIdAndParentIdAndTextContaining(Long userId, Long parentId, String text, Pageable pageable);

    Page<TodoEntity> findByUserIdAndParentId(Long userId, Long parentId, Pageable pageable);

    TodoEntity findByUserIdAndId(Long userId, Long id);


}
```

Lets take **findByUserIdAndParentId** as example

Comment: are you using spring-data repositories?

Comment: Yes exactly. Using JPARepostiory

Comment: show your repository and may be a query method on which you want to sort

Comment: try `findByUserIdAndIdOrderByChildern_SortOrder(Long userId, Long id);
`

Comment: No unfortunately that does not work. Maybe to also make it clearer. I want that all children are sorted properly.
Right now the children in OneToMany are sorted randomly. I want them to sort by either sortOrder or creationDate or updateDate

Comment: what do you meant by doesn't work? the above query will sort by sortorder of children, You can also Append Desc or Asc for ascending or descending

Comment: If you fail with @pvpkiran option, then you can write by yourself `@Query` using SPeL notation on top of the repository method.

Answer (score 0):

Use jpa query and generate the order by clause dynamically